# Adding multiple facebook page tabs from single facebook application using php

Tags: facebook-page

I have created a facebook application.
Now i want that using this application i need to add multiple pagetabs in a page.

and all of this i want to do in php
I have completed following steps

1) Logged in to facebook using my php script and got authenticaticationc code for managing pages.
2) Retrieved the list of pages i have in loged in users profile.

Now i don't know how to add a page tab in facebook programmatically.
I know there is a manual option and that is in applications settings to add a page tab

but I want to add it Programmatic using php.

Any help will be very appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Applications are allowed to have one Page Tab. So if you need to have multiple tabs for same app on single page where is no way to achieve this.

If you desire to add tabs for other applications you just need to issue `POST` with page `access_token` (from `accounts` connection of user who is admin of that page) request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=APPLICATION_ID&access_token=...
```

You need either repeat that step for every `APPLICATION_ID` you want to be added as tab or [Batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). Read more on page tabs creation in [documentation for `page` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)

Comment: Hi Scripter , can you please specify an example for posting to a page tab using the address you provided, i tried to understand using the documentation , it is returning true but not adding the tab over there ?

Comment: Visiting the URL I've provided (just substitute page `access_token`) is an example. If the response you get is `true` than tab should be added, if it's not the case file a bug using Facebook [Bug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs).

Comment: @Banna, What [Explorer Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) return for path `/PAGEID/tabs/app_APPID` (remember you need to use page `access_token` from `accounts` connection of user).

Comment: Hi I have used following code to post values on the graph api <form action="https://graph.facebook.com/175168785925593/tabs?app_id=My_App_Id&access_token=My_Token" method="post">
<input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="http://123sampleresume.com/syonFB/sample.php?pgId=4">
<input type="text" name="custom_name" id="custom_name" value="MLink">
<input type="text" name="is_permanent" id="is_permanent" value="1">

<input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: when i am using graph api explorer , i am passing the post method and fieldname id and value "allurls_1236584952314543" and it is returning "Invalid token: \"175168785925593\". An ID has already been specified." please help its very urgent

Comment: @Banna, seems that you trying not to create/add tab, but posting something on it which isn't possible! Page tabs are applications and not part of the page, every application shoul manage content on it's own.

Comment: @Banna, in Graph Explorer you need to use path `175168785925593/tabs/app_APPID` (replace only `APPID` with id of your app and leave `app_` prefix as is) to get info about specific tab for page `175168785925593`.

Comment: hmmm but i am using post method , and it is saying invalid token

Comment: ok leave that howaway i found a method to add tab and show my content in it , but now can you please suggest how i can change the tab name from php :)

Comment: @Banna, You'll get invalid token exception if using user access token instead of page access token. As for the name change consider asking this as separate question.